# How to understand an alternative definition of the ring of integers of a global field?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to understand Proposition 4-35 on page 164 of the book "Fourier Analysis on Number Fields" by Ramakrishnan and Valenza, the proof of which is omitted from the text. The set-up is as follows.

A **global field** is a finite (separable) extension of either $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbf{F}_q(t)$. A **place** on a field $\mathbf{F}$ is an equivalence class $v$ of absolute value functions $|\cdot | : \mathbf{F} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ under the relation $|\cdot | \sim | \cdot |'$ if there exists $s > 0$ such that $|a|' = |a|^s$ for all $a \in \mathbf{F}$. A place $v$ on a global field $K$ is called **finite** if

$\bullet$ $v$ restricts to a $p$-adic place on $\mathbb{Q}$ (char $K = 0$), or

$\bullet$ $v$ restricts to a $p(t)$-adic place on $\mathbf{F}_q(t)$ (char $K > 0$) for some prime $p(t) \in \mathbf{F}_q[t]$.

Now fix a global field $K$, and define the **ring of integers** of $K$ to be
$$ \mathcal{O}_K =  \bigcap_{v \text{ finite}} \{x \in K \mid |x| \leq 1 \text{ for all } |\cdot | \in v \}$$

The proposition then asserts the following:

(i) $\mathcal{O}_K$ is Noetherian, integrally closed (in its field of fractions), and every prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ is maximal. Equivalently, $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a Dedekind domain.

(ii) If $K$ has zero (respectively, positive) characteristic, then $\mathcal{O}_K$ is equal to the integral closure in $K$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ (respectively, $\mathbf{F}_q[t]$).

For one of the containments in (ii), if one defines $\mathcal{O}_K'$ to be the integral closure in $K$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ (respectively, $\mathbf{F}_q[t]$), then the containment $\mathcal{O}_K' \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K$ follows from the fact that the subring $\mathcal{O_v} := \{x \in K \mid |x|_v \leq 1\}$ of $K$ is integrally closed, hence $\mathcal{O}_K' \subseteq \mathcal{O}_v$, for each finite place $v$ on $K$. As for the rest of the proof, I would greatly appreciate some help or a reference to a text which might have a proof of this result.

Comment: I'm fairly sure [Matsumura](https://www.amazon.com/Commutative-Cambridge-Studies-Advanced-Mathematics/dp/0521367646) has this. IIRC the game is played using valuation rings. If an element is not in $\mathcal{O}'_K$, then a valuation ring not containing it can be constructed. It's been quite a few years, so I'm not betting the farm :-(

Comment: For (i), you could consult Cassels-Fröhlich's ANT, prop.§2 of chapter 1 (1, not 2) . For (ii), you could use the classical property that  $O_K $ is a Dedekind domain, or more directly, consider minimal polynomials as in @reuns' s answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $K \subset \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ a number field, and for some $\alpha \in K$ let its minimal polynomial be $$f(x) = x^d + \sum_{n=0}^{d-1} a_n x^n = \prod_{j=1}^d (x-\alpha_j)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$$

- If for some prime $p$ : $|\alpha|_p > 1$ then $|a_0|_p = |\prod_{j=1}^d \alpha_j|_p  > 1 \implies a_0 \not \in \mathbb{Z} \implies \alpha \not \in \overline{\mathbb{Z}}$.
- Conversely if $|\alpha|_p \le 1$ then $\forall j, |\alpha_j|_p \le 1$ thus $f(x) = \prod_{j=1}^d (x-\alpha_j) \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$.

  And hence $\forall p,|\alpha|_p \le 1 \implies \forall p, f \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x] \implies f \in \mathbb{Z}[x] \implies \alpha \in \overline{\mathbb{Z}}$.

It should work the same way for algebraic extensions of $\mathbf{F}_q(t)$.

Comment: (you need to justify why $|\alpha_j|_p$ doesn't depend on $j$)